# PHP - Best way to get adjacent records in db query

Tags: php

I am running into this situation where I have got a blog list page and blog detail pages. In each blog post page, I need to include navigations, i.e. Prev/Next buttons(links). I am just wondering what's the best way to get the next or previous post of the current post.

Say in the post page I have `$post = Blog::getPost()`, in blog list page I have `$posts = Blog::getPostsCollection()`, What's the most efficient way of getting the next/previous post in the post page, following the sorting criteria used in `Blog::getPostsCollection()` method?

For now I can only think of making collection object available in the detail page again and combine with things such as `array_search()` etc to generate the prev/next links, which I consider very inefficient.

Appreciate any input on this!

Answer (score 0):

What I most often do is to have a field called "insertDate" ("publishDate" in your case) and you can get the next/prev post in same category by getting the next "date" before/after the current post with DateDiff.

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, if not I hope that helps somebody else at least :)

Comment: Problem with this is you know your list is sorted by this field, but in reality the sort criteria could be different or even compounded, like sorted by last name, then first name, etc. So basically there is no way to do this directly from a db query.